# Perform date split and get count of records for the given time period(2 Date Columns) using SQL

Tags: sql, db2

My Input Table data looks like below

| ID | From Date | To Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GHI | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| GHI | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| ABC | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-31 |
| ABC | 2016-02-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| ABC | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-31 |
| ABC | 2016-02-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| ABC | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-31 |
| ABC | 2016-02-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| DEF | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| DEF | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| DEF | 2016-01-01 | 2016-10-24 |
| DEF | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| JKL | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| JKL | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| JKL | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| JKL | 2016-01-01 | 2016-03-04 |
| JKL | 2016-04-01 | 2016-12-31 |
| JKL | 2016-01-01 | 2016-03-04 |
| JKL | 2016-04-01 | 2016-12-31 |

I want my output to look like this, basically the count based on ID and time period(from and to date).
eg:
Simple Case:
For ID GHI there are 2 records covering the entire period hence the count 2.

Moderately complex Case:
Let us consider ID DEF there are 4 records here
3 covering period 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31
and 1 covering 2016-01-01 to 2016-10-24.

Step 1:
from the above case I know my minimum period is 2016-01-01 and maximum period is 2016-12-31.

Step 2:
based on the records in the table for this ID, I will go about deriving the dates splits and it will be
2016-01-01 to 2016-10-24
and
2016-10-25 to 2016-12-31

Step 3: Getting count on the records covered for that period.
it will become

2016-01-01 to 2016-10-24 (Count=4 as there are 4 records for DEF ID covering this period)
and
2016-10-25 to 2016-12-31 (Count=3 as there are only 3 records for DEF ID covering this period)

| ID | From Date | To Date | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GHI | 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-31 | 02 |
| ABC | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-31 | 03 |
| ABC | 2016-02-01 | 2016-12-31 | 03 |
| DEF | 2016-01-01 | 2016-10-24 | 04 |
| DEF | 2016-10-25 | 2016-12-31 | 03 |
| JKL | 2016-01-01 | 2016-03-04 | 05 |
| JKL | 2016-03-05 | 2016-03-31 | 03 |
| JKL | 2016-04-01 | 2016-12-31 | 05 |

Comment: I am not sure on how to approach this, I would like this to be done with db2 but I am okay if this could be achieved with any other RDBMS. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *for ID GHI there are 2 records covering the entire period hence the count 2.* I do NOT see where you define what is "entire period"... now this looks like trivial grouping by 3 columns...

Comment: GHI was the easiest so I had it on top, Period might be dynamic per ID so we will have to derive them ourselves before we could get the count over them.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT ID, [From Date], [To Date], COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY ID, [From Date], [To Date]
```

You would want to use `GROUP BY` to combine rows which match on certain columns, and then  you want to get the COUNT(*) for the number of records that are contained within each of those groups.

Follow some tutorials on a learning site, this would be covered very early on:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure if you had the opportunity to look into the JKL ID where you might have to derive the dates and then get count based on that. This simple group by might not work :)

Comment: @HariPrasshanth I think you'll need to edit your post and provide a more detailed explanation of what you want. Otherwise everyone is going to think this is a simple grouping solution.

Comment: Thanks @Chad Baldwin I will do it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT ID,FROMDATE,TODATE,COUNT(*) FROM TABLE
GROUP BYID,FROMDATE,TODATE
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure if you had the opportunity to look into the JKL ID where you might have to derive the dates and then get count based on that. This simple group by might not work :)